# No code coverage for static library in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, static-libraries, xcode7, code-coverage

I have a static library with pods. I don't see any thing under coverage tab. Shows coverage for test bundles only. I have searched numerous place, but couldn't find a conclusive answer. Some where in Xcode 7 Beta it was not supported and then it was added back. I don't find any notes on apple docs that code coverage is not supported for static libraries. Is anyone able to see code coverage for static libraries on Xcode 7?

Comment: I would like an answer to this also could instrument program flow being disabled be the cause ?

Comment: i tried those old flags too. They don't work, nothing shows up on Coverage tab

Answer (score 0):

Try Slather https://github.com/venmo/slather

Coverage for code included via CocoaPods

If you're trying to compute the coverage of code that has been included via CocoaPods, you will need to tell CocoaPods to use the Slather plugin by adding the following to your Podfile.

plugin 'slather'

Comment: slather is not working for my static library, issue here : https://github.com/venmo/slather/issues/111#issuecomment-167990242

Answer (score 0):

Use slather  https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather

You will still need to change the xcode project settings so that it can generate the coverage data. Xcode will not show coverage data for static libraries.

Slather will then show it to you nicely, you can opt for an html /  command line / cobertura xml output.